# is it safe to use Debug Folder files for distribution?

Tags: c#

is it safe to use Debug Folder files for distribution ? or I should use release folder .

I use vs 2008 express edition .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be safe as such, but you should really distribute the release version. The debug versions might have special debugging code in them that shouldn't be in a production system and might also be a bit slower since it's not optimized.

You can find out some of what gets optimized in this blog post: [What does the optimize switch do?](https://web.archive.org/web/20151130080457/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The release folder will have some additional optimizations that the debug folder will not.  If you are considering the debug folder in order to help troubleshoot production type issues, it may be better to use the release folder, but turn on some level of logging through configuration files.  I would hate to have my clients see some nasty debug popup dialog!